# SSL Certificate Issue Godaddy + DigitalOcean + Nginx

Tags: server, nginx, ssl

I follow digitalocean tutorial - how to install godaddy certificate with nginx. Everything worked fine expect it's not showing green color in chrome or lock in safari.

I tested certificate with godaddy and showing me chain anchor issue.

Godaddy Result : https://casecurity.ssllabs.com/analyze.html?viaform=on&d=yourserviceconnection.com

Here is how i did:

```
cat website.com.crt godaddy-intermediate.crt > chained.crt
```

In Nginx :

```
server {

        server_name website.com;

        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private//new.key;

        root /var/www/html/website.com/public/;
        index index.html index.php index.htm index.hh;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
        location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
                fastcgi_keep_conn on;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: This isn't really about Ubuntu, but I can tell you that the reason the green "Lock" icon won't appear is because of the fact that not all of the resources on your page are loaded from HTTPS sources. You need to fix the actual HTML/JS/CSS/etc of your site to only use HTTPS.

Comment: HTML ? do i need to add meta tag something ?

Comment: Anytime you import any other source (even embedding an image) you need to make it uses an HTTPS URL instead of HTTP. It's a lot more than a meta-tag.